# How to connect to Sybase IQ16 using Go?

Tags: go, odbc, sap-iq

I have an idea to write an application to work with SAP Sybase IQ16 server using Go language. Platform windows/nix does not matter yet. I had worked with this database using C# later, and I remember, that there was no ADO.NET driver, so I used ODBC and `iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.v4.0.dll` to establish connection. Also, I know, that drivers for IQ, ASE, etc... are not compatible. I looked here https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SQLDrivers, but neither оf drivers seems to be compatible. Thus, I can not understand at all is there solution for my problem.

Comment: There is [`github.com/alexbrainman/odbc`](https://github.com/alexbrainman/odbc) which you could try to use with that whateverAnywhereX.Y.dll

Comment: The wikipedia page and [this](https://help.sap.com/viewer/a894a54d84f21015b142ffe773888f8c/16.1.3.0/en-US/a3171c5084f210159caebadd9e149481.html) say Sybase IQ 16.0 provides native ODBC drivers (that "anywhere" thingy appears to be a .NET assembly).